# How to search a string in multiple columns within a table-value function in a better way?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

UDF:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[udf_GetActivity] 
    (@XWILDCARDSEARCH NVARCHAR(100))
RETURNS 
     @TABLE TABLE (SRCCODE NVARCHAR(10), 
                   DESCRPTN NVARCHAR(100), 
                   PARENTTRANID NVARCHAR(10), 
                   INVOICE NVARCHAR(50), 
                   PERIOD NVARCHAR(7), 
                   REF NVARCHAR(20), 
                   CURRCODE NVARCHAR(10), 
                   DEPARTMENT NVARCHAR(10), 
                   INVCDATE DATETIME, 
                   RECPTTYPEID NVARCHAR(20), 
                   RECPTNO NVARCHAR(20), 
                   ADDLDESC NVARCHAR(1000)
                  )
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @TABLE
        SELECT 
            A.SOURCECODE, A.DESCRIPTION, 
            B.PARENTTRANSID, B.INVOICE, 
            A.PERIOD, A.REF, B.CURRENCYCODE, ... 
            A.ADDITIONALDESCRIPTION
        FROM 
            TABLEA A
        JOIN 
            TABLEB B ON A.SOURCECODE = B.SOURCECODE

    RETURN
END
```

The parameter of `@XWILDCARDSEARCH` could be any string(`'09', 'rent', 'invc93', '2'`).

Use of the following columns to filter the table result by the parameter. Looking for something like

```
WHERE A.DESCRIPTION LIKE '%' + @XWILDCARDSEARCH+ '%'
   OR A.REF LIKE '%' + @XWILDCARDSEARCH+ '%'
   OR B.INVOICE LIKE '%' + @XWILDCARDSEARCH+ '%'
```

1. DESCRIPTION
2. INVOICE
3. REF

This is working fine but very slow and so wonder is any other way to get this done in a best way?

Comment: It would help to include a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and show exactly how you are using the parameters currently in the full query.

Comment: Thanks, Removed the unnecessary parameters and now the function takes only one parameter.

Comment: So what is stopping you from implementing and testing your "like this" approach?

Comment: This is working but wonder is any other best way to get this done.

Comment: [duplicate on database](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/299147/how-to-search-a-string-within-a-function-in-sql-server).

Comment: Removed the duplicate question.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the use of indexes to speed-up your query is not possible if the searched string starts with a wildcard (that's your case).

You can use **full-text search** (preferably on the database replica), this approach needs the creation of full-text indexes and is a well-fitted solution if you need to search on multiple columns

`A LIKE query against millions of rows of text data can take minutes to return; whereas a full-text query can take only seconds or less against the same data, depending on the number of rows that are returned.`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/search/full-text-search?view=sql-server-ver15

Alternatively, you can use another technology like ElasticSearch
https://www.elastic.co/